# Why namespased: false does not work for me

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have seen similar questions. But I lose something and can't understand why it does not work in my case.
I have the following vuex module:

```
const root = {
    namespaced: false,
    state: {
        advertisersOptions: [],
        customersTypesOptions: [],
       // ... more state props are here ...
    },
    mutations: {
        setIsChoiceAllApps(state, isChoiceAllApps) {
            state.isChoiceAllApps = isChoiceAllApps;
        },

       // and so on 
    },
    getters: {
        getErrorMessages: state => {
            return state.errorMessages;
        },
        // and so on
    },
    actions: {},
};

export default root
```

I create my store like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as Vuex from 'vuex'
import root from './modules/root'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
         root
    }
});
```

And I include it into the `app.js` file:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    components: {
        Multiselect
    },
});
```

So, I would like to see my vuex properties after `...mapState(['...'])`. I will show you the component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            choiceAllApplications: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['updateApplicationsAction']),
        disposeAllApps: function () {
            this.$store.commit("setApplications", []);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            "advertisersOptions",
            "advertisersSelected",
            // and so on are here
        ]),
    },
```

As you can see I use `namespaced: false,`. I just want to see my properties in the global scope.  But it does not work. I will make `console.log` inside the `mounted()` and this is the dump:

[image]

As you can see module name (`root`) is here. I forgot something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't forgot anything, it is always like this - as per [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html), only `getters, setters and actions` are subject to be namespaced (and, btw, even then they are namespaces, they will still be present in global object but be like `moduleName/action` - `user/getUserName` and not inside objects like `user.getUserName`).

However `state` is always per module - so, not matter namespaced or not it will sit in it's own property in the global state object.